# Why does this expression return 2 in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I would think you might get `0`, maybe because the strings are turned to `1's` and the `-` operator causes a subtraction operation to take place?

```
"1" - - "1";
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But isn't 1-(-1) = 1+1 = 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-` casts the string to a number and also acts as a minus sign.

`1 - (-1)` = `1 + 1` = `2`

Answer (score 11):

It's how math works

```
1 - (-1) = 1 + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - (-1) = 2. 
I dont see the issue? JavaScript will parse those as integers because of the minus sign, expecting math.
It also happens if you multiply a numerical string by 1, aka the poor man's parseInt().